# How to change entire pdf pages background color white to other color in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

Using pdfkit gem. I have to change entire pdf pages default background color white to other color.. how achieve this..

Added below code:-

```
<BODY style=\"background-color:#04b4b4;\">
```

But it is not covering all pages, in last it covering only data area,(like below image)... [image]

Update:-

```
gem 'pdfkit', '0.5.0'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

pdfkit.rb

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size     => 'Letter',
    :margin_top    => '0in',
    :margin_right  => '0in',
    :margin_bottom => '1.0in',
    :margin_left   => '0in'
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it in a stylesheet for your PDF file then load it into your PDFKit like this:

```
  # init your pdfkit as usual
  kit = PDFKit.new(your_html, options)
  # load the stylesheet file
  kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/your-style-sheet.css"
  # then build it or do what ever you want.
  kit.to_pdf
```

in your-style-sheet.css

```
body {
  background: #04b4b4;
}
```

Comment: added, but if last page has some data, background color covering only where data is present reaming page is white..

Comment: No @FunctionalRocking, do you find any solution?

Comment: @khalidh I have I added a bunch of empty paragraphs and remove the last page with `pdftk` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204839/wkhtmltopdf-background-color-doesnt-fill-second-page/51215085#51215085